# Tracking Sleep with the new watch

Tags: apple-watch

Is there built in functionality for the Watch 3 to track my sleep patterns?  Is there anything that figures out sleep cycles and duration, and tracks heart rate at the same time for a prelimnary analysis?

Answer (score 3):

The Apple Watch doesn't currently have built-in sleep tracking functionality. However, there are some excellent third-party apps that can track your sleep. [Sleep++](https://david-smith.org/blog/2016/02/11/introducing-sleep-plus-plus-2-dot-0/) is one of the more popular options, and it's free. However, Sleep++ doesn't track heart rate itself, instead leaving you to use the Apple Health app's built-in heart rate tracker. Another great choice is [Sleep Diary](https://apptag.me/sleep/), which *does* track heart rate, and seems to have a wealth of features.

This is just from some quick research - I don't personally do any sleep tracking with my Apple Watch, as I charge it overnight.